# Custom List view button with multiple record selection - open in new window

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a list view button that generates a set of PDFs based multiple record selection, using the standardsetcontroller. This all works fine, however, the PDFs are generated in the same tab so the user has to hit the back button once they've generated and saved the PDFs.

I've tried using window.open() to open in a new tab, however this loses the multiple record selection and getSelected() returns null.

There appeared to be a solution [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Ai2YIAS) but this returns an error of " Cannot set property 'Target' of undefined"

Any other ideas of how to achieve this?

Comment: Please share your code on what you have tried so far?

Comment: there's not much code to it, if you set the list button to a visualforce page you don't have the option to open in a new window and if i use window.open("/apex/myVFPage"); the multiple record selection is lost